# How to pass objects between custom WxListView and main program context?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have an wxWidgets application that parses data from a file and stores it into an object. The data stored within the object is mixed types, float, string etc.

```
class data {
float mData1, mData2;
string mID;
int export(const char *filepath);
}
```

on file open the data is read from file into individual data objects and stored in a vector.

```
//parse each entry into a dataParsed object.
std::shared_ptr<data> dataParsed = std::make_shared<data>();
...
...
//Example: 10 entries in the file are parsed into individal objects and stored in parsedFile
std::vector<data> parsedFile.push_back(dataParsed);
```

This vector `parsedFile` is then processed into a custom wxListCtrl for presentation.

```
//populate custom list control
for(auto d : parsedFile) {
    //convert data contained within d to string
    //push data back into listview object
    wxCustomListView.push_back(std::to_string(d.mData1), std::to_string(mData2), mID);
}
```

I have implemented a context menu in my custom wxListControl. This has a method to export the individual selected element. However, I no longer have access to the original parsed data object `parsedFile` and the objects export function. I have to access the data from the `wxCustomListView` vector and rebuild the format and create a new `data` object that allows me to export.

Is there a way to pass the selected index back to the main wxPanel and process the export in this context? I'm not sure if i should be building my context menu in the custom wxListCtrl or in the main panel itself. Doing this would save a lot of time converting data and creating new objects when they already exist in a different context.

Example Custom Listview:

```
class CustomListViewCtrl : public wxListCtrl {
public:
    CustomListViewCtrl(wxWindow *parent, const wxWindowID id, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxListCtrl(parent, id, pos, size, wxLC_REPORT | wxLC_VIRTUAL | wxLC_SINGLE_SEL)
        {

        this->AppendColumn("Index");
        this->SetColumnWidth(0, 80);
        this->AppendColumn("ID");
        this->SetColumnWidth(1, 180);
        this->AppendColumn("Data 1");
        this->SetColumnWidth(2, 200);
        this->AppendColumn("Data 2");
 
        BuildContextMenu();
        this->Bind(wxEVT_CONTEXT_MENU, &CustomListViewCtrl::OnContextMenuEvent, this);
    }

    virtual wxString OnGetItemText(long index, long column) const wxOVERRIDE {
        ListData item = items[index];

        switch (column) {
            case 0: return std::to_string(item.index);
            case 1: return item.ID;
            case 2: return item.data1;
            case 3: return item.data2;
            default: return "";
        }
    }

    void RefreshAfterUpdate() {
        this->SetItemCount(items.size());
        this->Refresh();
    }

    std::vector<ListData> items;
    wxMenu m_ContextMenu;

    void BuildContextMenu();
    void OnContextMenuEvent(wxContextMenuEvent &);

    void ctxShowRows(wxCommandEvent &e);
    void ctxExportSelected(wxCommandEvent &e); // Export Method pulls data from the listview and puts it into a new data object to access the export() method.
};
```

Comment: at which point that vector disappear? And why? The wxListCtrl should be put on some container, right? So why not keep a list as a member of this container and not just pass it in and forget about it...